# determine if a record is new or existing?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm overriding the new and the edit task button. In both cases, I want to use the same extension class, but i need to determine if the record is a new one or existing one (i.e. is this a new case or edit).

Any ideas?

Here's the relevant part of the constructor

```
public ActivityRouterExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

    String type = Controller.getRecord().getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
    setActivityInfo(type, controller);   

}


private void setActivityInfo(String type, ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    if (type == 'Task'){
      this.actType= 'Task';
      this.theTask = (Task)controller.getRecord();
     }
  if (type == 'Event'){
        this.actType= 'Event';
        this.theEvent = (Event)controller.getRecord();
}

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just check for the presence of Id?

```
Id recordId = controller.getId();

if (recordId == null) {
    System.debug('Looks like insert');
} else {
    System.debug('Looks like update');
}
```

Of course you can do same with `controller.getRecord().get('Id')`, once you have your Task/Event.

Alternatively, you could check the page parameters, but it seems like a bit of going around to achieve something simple...